# OkHTTP Client Java initialization: should it be static or just final?

Tags: java, okhttp

I'm using OkHttp library in my java application. I have a class that makes requests and uses `OkHttpClient` class, which is then used in other 2 classes.

```
Class A {
 private static final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
 public Response makeRequest(...) { ... }
}
Class B {
 private static final A a = new A();
 void doB() { try(var temp = a.makeRequest()) { ... } }
}
Class C {
 private static final A a = new A();
 void doC() { try(var temp = a.makeRequest()) { ... } }
}
```

My question is: should the field `OkHttpClient` in the `A.class` be static or just final? Becuase if it's static, then usages of `A` can be static (because there's no fields in `A.class`). Classes `B` and `C` later can be created and used multiple times in the different threads. Is it normal to use OkHttpClient like that or it should be just `private final OkHttpClient` ? I'm confused because in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888240/okhttp-application-level-okhttpclient-instance) someone's saying it's okay to use it with `static`, but in the [official documentation they're referring to](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html) usage example shows creating it only with `final` modifier.

Comment: It should be a singleton.

Comment: @tgdavies so it should be enough to create it with static keyword if I'm not creating it anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `static` because `OkHttpClient` supports multithreading. This way you get shared caching and pooling across all http calls.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48533265/410939